# Are char name[50]; and char *name; name = (char *) malloc(50 * sizeof(char)); the same?

Tags: c

Here is my code:
I've commented `char newName[50];`
I tried the same thing using both `malloc` and `newName[50]`. But the file doesn't compile if I don't use `malloc`. Aren't both of them the same thing? I thought that they were same; now I'm confused.
Please clarify the difference between the two declarations:

1. `char newName[50];`     and
2. `char *newName;`
   `newName = (char *) malloc(50 * sizeof(char));`

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char* checkName(char *s);

int main(void)
{
    char name[50];
    scanf("%s", name);

    char *newName;

    newName = (char *) malloc(50 * sizeof(char));

    //  char newName[50];
    newName = checkName(name);

    printf("%s", newName);
}

char* checkName(char *s)
{
    int i = 0, j = 1;
    int l = strlen(s);
    char name[50];
    strcpy(name, s);

    while(j)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < l; ++i)
        {
            if(s[i] < 65 || (s[i] > 90 && s[i] < 97) || s[i] > 122)
            {
                printf("\nOnly alphabets are allowed, please Re-enter your name : ");
                scanf("%s", s); 
                j = 1;
                continue;
            }
            else
                j = 0;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: The malloc line is redundant anyway and could be removed, since you immediately reassign `newName` in the next line

Comment: There are better tools than the `if` condition in the function — such as `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>`.  Using `'A'`, `'Z'`, `'a'` and `'z'` would be better than using numbers, too.  The better term is "Only letters are allowed".

Comment: Hint: `sizeof(char)` is _always_ 1, as `sizeof` measures size in multiples of `char` size. So `sizeof(char)` is like asking "how many apples are one apple?", so you can just use `1`, i.e. `malloc(50)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer)

Comment: I'm particularly confused about character arrays and their pointers. And @M.M said that the malloc line is redundant, why is that so, I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not the same.

```
char name[50];
```

creates a char array of 50 bytes on the stack (at least in your case).

```
char * name;
name = malloc(50); // no need to cast the malloc() result
```

creates a char pointer and points it to a memory area of 50 bytes allocated on the heap.

Both ways to do it are wrong if you do

```
newName = checkName(name);
```

on the next step, because

- in version 1 that won't work (you cannot assign a `char *` as returned by `checkName()` to a `char[]`) and
- in version 2 that will make you lose access to your allocated block (that's called a memory leak).

If you want `checkName()` to act on a memory area you pass to it, you should, well, pass one to it.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about why version 2 won't work, and what's memory leak?

Comment: @TanishSharma I think there are resources on the internet which can explain a memory leak in a more concise way than I can. But in short, if you `malloc()` a memory area and lose its pointer, you cannot `free()` it again and the memory remains blocked forever (i. e. until you terminate your program).